# Minecraft Classic no link given but world destroyed

Tags: minecraft-classic-browser

I had a world and I went to sleep. When I joined back (never gave anyone a link) there were blocks placed like coal (which I don't even think you can get), plus  a 32x32 hole 4 feet down at my base.

Is there a way someone could acces my world with no link?

Answer (score -1):

You'll be relieved to hear that there is no way that anyone can access your world without a link.
Your experience seems to have been a glitch from the information given.